# how to identify log4j2 or log4j in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, log4j2

We are using maven project and need to check we are using log4j or log4j2 in the java application .
Please guide me the best practice
below is my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- Avoid warnings about platform encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    
    <powermock.version>1.6.2</powermock.version>
    <log4j.version>2.3</log4j.version>
</properties><dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency><dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    </project>
```

Comment: Look at the output from `dependency:tree`

Comment: hi ,am new to maven .please can you share the snippet code

Comment: You could read your pom file which is obvious that you are using log4j 2.x what's interesting are those two `-api` deps?... Also typical using a version 2.3 which is of 2015 !!! which means not updated a very long time...

Comment: hi @khmarbaise thanks for confirmation ie log4j2.v version ,what is log4j2 maven latest version?

Comment: You should check central repository: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.logging.log4j and also check https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: @kiranchandkothuru do you have a more experienced developer on your team?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to print the tree of dependencies including the version.

Afterward just look for `log4`:

`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep log4`

Alternatively use `mvn dependency:list` to list the dependencies.

`mvn dependency:list | grep log4`